# Hi am new to hostgator cpanel.I get this database connection error when testing my website

Tags: php, mysql

I have hidden other details for security purposes

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user   'cPanelUsername_databaseUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home3/username/public_html/domai/AppINIT.php on line 25

```
appINIT.php configuration settings

<?php
$db_host        = "localhost";
$db_port        = "80";
$db_user        = "cPanelUsername_databaseUsername";
$db_password    = "xxxxxxx";
$db_name        = "cPanelUsername_databaseName";
define("EXT", '.php');
$licensekey = ""; #License Key
$secret = "yyyy";  #Secuirity Salt

?>
//prepared statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from appconfig"); $stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: either user name or the password or the host name is incorrect.

Comment: The MySQL port is 3306, port 80 is for HTTP requests.
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/commonly-used-port-numbers

Of course getting your code to work is not HostGator's responsibility, but they are generally willing to take a look to see if they can get it to work for you if you ask nicely! And the error message strongly supports the answer already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $dbh variable, so you can't call prepare() on it.

Comment: The script works perfectly well when tested locally with xampp server.The error just showed up after i uploaded the website files.I have changed the port to 3306 but still the error persists.

Comment: Then the code you have posted here isn't what you have locally. In fact, it could never throw the error you've specified because the statement erroring is outside the php tags. Please give us the actual code.